# I'm using cache and minifying but site is slow , how to fix?

Tags: wordpress, performance, browser-cache, minify, pagespeed

I have used cache and also minifying but it's load time is over 80 seconds !
the Url : http://www.abretalaee.com/

Comment: Maybe the webserver is to slow or the bandwith is to small.

Comment: Should I change my webserver ?

Answer (score 1):

Analyze your site’s speed and make it faster through  https://gtmetrix.com/

Comment: I have used that tool and it shows a nice score for my site but site loading time is about 80-90 seconds :|

Comment: can you check grade,

Comment: please optimize the image

Comment: yeah it shows me B grade for site speed and D for Yslow

Comment: any external stylesheet or jquery?

Comment: 2 external JS I have

Comment: //cdn.sendpulse.com/js/push/ae6143297912b629d82a6152f7eb590a_0.js

Comment: just check 'yslow' tab

Comment: It shows me , Add expires headers  & use CDN & make fewer http requests & use cookie free domains